# How do I create a Palantir Foundry Fusion sync for a timestamp column?

Tags: palantir-foundry, fusion

I want to create a Fusion-backed dataset in Foundry. Usually, I would create the columns and set the types but when I add a timestamp column it turns up as null in the dataset:

[image: A table with a column titled 'my_timestamp' in Fusion, with values such as '2022-08-30T11:09:39Z'. It is synced to a dataset with the export column type of the column set to 'Timestamp']

[image: Dataset preview showing a column 'my_timestamp' and null values in the column]

How do I add a timestamp column to a Fusion table and sync it to a dataset correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For timestamps, you should use the format:

`YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`

For example:

`2022-08-30 11:09:39`

This will result in the dataset sync completing successfully.

You can check the valid formats by setting the cell data type to timestamp, and hovering over the <kbd>?</kbd> icon. This will also highlight the cell with a red underline if it does not match the expected format.

[image: The data type dropdown in the Fusion sheet header set to 'Date and Time']
[image: A pop-up from a question mark icon, explaining the supported timestamp formats]

Comment: You can also use the `=Timestamp()` function if you're manually entering values or need to take other columns as inputs. Docs: https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/fusion/function-library/#timestampyear-number-month-number-day-number-hour-number-minute-number-second-number-date_time